# Looking for script to split the value of a column into another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for a query to split value of one column into another column, below are the examples with the current column with the value along with the expecting new column.

### Existing Column:

```
Asset
ora-abacogp.de.hsbc, 1626, ABACOGP 
frlooraprda1.systems.uk.hsbc, 60002, ABM00
fr00parp0845ora.hibm.sub.fr.hsbc, 1521, ACC
hkp02lp1802s-rs6000.hk.hsbc, 50000, ACMHKPU1:ACRMUTF
actcoreprod.us.hsbc, 1700, ACTCOREP
frloo10g1prd.systems.uk.hsbc, 1521, ADN00
ae0w0dic5073.hbeu.adroot.hsbc, 56091, AE0W0DIC5073\LIVE801MSSQL
MTW00130511.HBEU.ADROOT.HSBC, 1521, ARISTION
IGASMALTA.HBEU.ADROOT.HSBC, 1521, IGASDBL
ssuml527.systems.uk.hsbc, 1521, LMSPEGA1
```

### Expecting with new column:

```
Asset                                                              DBName
ora-abacogp.de.hsbc, 1626, ABACOGP                                 ABACOGP
frlooraprda1.systems.uk.hsbc, 60002, ABM00                         FRLOORAPRDA1
fr00parp0845ora.hibm.sub.fr.hsbc, 1521, ACC                        FR00PARP0845ORA
hkp02lp1802s-rs6000.hk.hsbc, 50000, ACMHKPU1:ACRMUTF               HKP02LP1802
actcoreprod.us.hsbc, 1700, ACTCOREP                                ACTCOREPROD
frloo10g1prd.systems.uk.hsbc, 1521, ADN00                          FRLOO10G1PRD
ae0w0dic5073.hbeu.adroot.hsbc, 56091, AE0W0DIC5073\LIVE801MSSQL    AE0W0DIC5073
MTW00130511.HBEU.ADROOT.HSBC, 1521, ARISTION                       MTW00130511
IGASMALTA.HBEU.ADROOT.HSBC, 1521, IGASDBL                          IGASMALTA
ssuml527.systems.uk.hsbc, 1521, LMSPEGA1                           SSUML527
```

As you can see in the fourth line I have value like `hkp02lp1802s` and in the new column I don't want 's' at the end it will be like `HKP02LP1802`.

Comment: Is this question about regexes? Do you want the last word separated by `.` or `-` preceding the first `.`?

Comment: What are all your rules?

Comment: Unless you can provide some rules on how you want to extract the DBName from your Asset data, there isn't a straight-forward answer. At the moment, the rules look a bit arbitrary: *Use the first contiguous string in the Assets value which ends with a `.`, provided it doesn't contain a dash, in which case either remove the characters before the dash. or the characters after the dash. If there is an `s` before a dash, then remove it as well...*

Answer (score 0):

REGEXP_REPLACE should suit your needs:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions137.htm#SQLRF06302

Try this query and adjust the regular expression if something more complex is required:

```
select  
        DBName,         
        regexp_replace(lower(Asset), '(' || lower(DBName) || ')[^.]', DBName) 
        from asset
```